# Avoiding GET before SET in a Redis counter

Tags: redis

I am interested in creating several different redis based counters in my web application. A lot of this stuff is basically for metrics etc, but that doesn't make a difference. My question is essentially the following, is it possible to avoid doing:

```
if $redis.get(key) != null
  // increment key
else
  // create key with a counter of 1
```

Ideally something like this would be more optimal

```
$redis.incr(key, 1) // increment key by 1, and if it does not exist, start it at the value 1
```

am I overlooking the redis documentation? Is there a way to do this currently?

Comment: But that's exactly what incr does.  Just pass it the key and you're done.  If the key does not exist, it will create it and set an initial value of 1.  If you want to use a different value use the incrby command.  See http://redis.io/commands/incrby and http://redis.io/commands/incr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a INCR command, which if the key does not exists sets the value of the key to 1

```
$redis.incr()
```

should work.

see http://redis.io/commands/incr